Healenium with Selenium returning java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException
Am integrating Selenium and Healenium and encountering the below error stack trace:
java.io.UncheckedIOException: java.net.ConnectException     at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute0(JdkHttpClient.java:439)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.AddSeleniumUserAgent.lambda$apply$0(AddSeleniumUserAgent.java:42)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.Filter.lambda$andFinally$1(Filter.java:55)
    at
org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.jdk.JdkHttpClient.execute(JdkHttpClient.java:355)
    at
com.epam.healenium.client.RestClient.getElements(RestClient.java:135)
    at
com.epam.healenium.SelfHealingEngine.loadStoredSelectors(SelfHealingEngine.java:169)
    at
com.epam.healenium.SelfHealingDriver.callInitActions(SelfHealingDriver.java:65)
    at
com.epam.healenium.SelfHealingDriver.create(SelfHealingDriver.java:42)
    at selhel.AmazonSearchTest.firstTest(AmazonSearchTest.java:26)  at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
Method)     at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)   at
org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at
org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at
org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at

Dependencies used are only the below ones:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.22.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.epam.healenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>healenium-web</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
</dependency>

Code:
package selhel;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;

import com.epam.healenium.SelfHealingDriver;

public class SearchTest {
    
    @Test
    public void firstTest()
    {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C://Program Files/ChromeDriver/chromedriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--remote-allow-origins=*");
        
        WebDriver delegate = new ChromeDriver(options);
        
        SelfHealingDriver driver = SelfHealingDriver.create(delegate);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Gmail']")).click();
        
        }
}

Can anyone help me in resolving this issue?

You can run getCause() on that exception to receive more details.  (include results in your question)  Use a try/catch on your initializations and methods there.

I am also getting same issue. Any solution for this ?
